# python - how to count the frequency of two strings in a row for a csv

Tags: python, csv, dataset

I have an external dataset which includes crime types and the precincts in which they occur, and I need to figure out how often a crime occurs in a precinct. What I would like to find would be a frequency table so that I could calculate how often the crime is committed in a specific precinct (ultimately need to create pie chart for each type of crime e.g. Rape, Robbery, etc)
This is what I have so far:

```
columns=defaultdict(list)

with open('Seattle_Crime_Stats_by_Police_Precinct_2008-Present.csv') as f:
    reader=csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        for (k,v) in row.items():
            columns[k].append(v)
crimes=(columns['CRIME_TYPE'])
precincts=(columns['Precinct'])
number=(columns['Row_Value_ID'])
count_crimes=Counter(crimes)
```

please help, I've been stuck on this for days (new to python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you read about pandas and use it, as it is going to greatly simplify all further processing. Here's how to begin: read the CSV file as a dataframe, group the data by the two variables, and convert into a table:

```
import pandas as pd
data = ps.read_csv("Seattle_Crime_Stats_by_Police_Precinct_2008-Present.csv")
data.groupby(["Precinct","CRIME_TYPE"]).count().unstack()
```

The last line may need to use `sum()` instead of `count()`; it's unclear what is the structure of your CSV file:

```
data.groupby(["Precinct","CRIME_TYPE"]).sum().unstack()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use value_counts() function:

```
dataframe_name['column_name'].value_counts()
```

This will give you frequency for all unique values.